# Haskell, a function declaration in a class

Tags: class, haskell, polymorphism, instance

i am trying to create some instances for a polymorph class Tree, but i dont get it,

look, my code is:

```
data BTree a = BLeaf a | BBranch a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving(Show)
data TTree a = TLeaf a | TBranch a (TTree a) (TTree a) (TTree a) deriving(Show)

class Tree a where

    getName :: a -> a -- How should i declare this function?

instance Tree (BTree a) where

    getName (BLeaf name) = name
    getName (BBranch name lhs rhs) = name

instance Tree (TTree a) where

    getName (TLeaf name) = name
    getName (TBranch name lhs mhs rhs) = name

test1 = getName (BLeaf 1)
test2 = getName (TLeaf 1)
```

GHCI says:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `BTree a'
```

So, How should i declare the getName-function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a typeclass parameter `t` for the type constructor (like `BTree` or `TTree`, and unlike `BTree a` and `TTree a`):

```
class Tree t where
    getName :: t a -> a

instance Tree BTree where
    getName (BLeaf name) = name
    getName (BBranch name lhs rhs) = name
```

If you need the instances to vary depending on the element type `a`, you need multi-parameter classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Tree t a where
    getName :: t a -> a

instance Tree BTree Int where
    getName (BLeaf name) = name+1
    getName (BBranch name lhs rhs) = name*2

instance Tree BTree Char where
    getName (BLeaf name) = name
    getName (BBranch name lhs rhs) = name
```

Probably you don't need to make it so general.